# How to run InternJS tests with extJS application

Tags: selenium, extjs, intern

I have a application developed in `extJS` and i am exploring **InternJS** to develop automated tests. But I can not run a simple test, I think missing some step because I have this error:

```
Error: Missing required argument "config"
  at PreExecutor.getConfig  <workspace/intern-tutorial-completed-tutorial-3.0.0/node_modules/intern/lib/executors/PreExecutor.js:145:11>
  at getConfig  <workspace/intern-tutorial-completed-tutorial-3.0.0/node_modules/intern/lib/executors/PreExecutor.js:379:17>
  at <workspace/intern-tutorial-completed-tutorial-3.0.0/node_modules/intern/browser_modules/dojo/Promise.js:156:41>
  at run  <workspace/intern-tutorial-completed-tutorial-3.0.0/node_modules/intern/browser_modules/dojo/Promise.js:51:33>
  at CallbackQueue.drain  <workspace/intern-tutorial-completed-tutorial-3.0.0/node_modules/intern/browser_modules/dojo/CallbackQueue.js:39:35>
  at MutationObserver.<anonymous>  <workspace/intern-tutorial-completed-tutorial-3.0.0/node_modules/intern/browser_modules/dojo/nextTick.js:52:27>
```

My folder structure is like this

```
   - app
   - bin
      chromedriver.exe
      phantomjs.exe
      selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
   - tests
      - functional
         index.js
      - unit
         hello.js
      Intern.js
   index.html
   package.json
```

I use this command to start selenium

```
java -jar bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

And i configure the **intern.js** file like this

```
define({
    capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.53.1'
    },
    environments: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome' 
            chromeOptions: {
                args: [ 'load-and-launch-app=../app/hello.js' ]
            }
        },
        {
            browserName: 'phantomjs'
        }
    ],
    maxConcurrency: 2,
    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
    loaderOptions: {
        packages: [ { name: 'app', location: '../app' } ]
    },
    loaders: {
        'host-node': 'requirejs',
        'host-browser': 'node_modules/requirejs/require.js'
    }
    suites: [ 'tests/unit/hello' ],
    functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional/index' ],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run Intern, you need to tell it where your config is. Assuming you're running WebDriver tests (since you're starting Selenium), you'd start Intern from your package base directory like:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/Intern.js
```